# Load an assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, private, gac, .net-assembly

I've used a tutorial (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908, method 1) to generate two projects. Project a has a reference to project b.

**project a:**

```
new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacRemove(string.Format(@"C:\Users\[me]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAssembly1\MyAssembly1\bin\Debug\MyAssembly1.dll"));
new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacInstall(string.Format(@"C:\Users\[me]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAssembly1\MyAssembly1\bin\Debug\MyAssembly1.dll"));
MyAssembly1.Class1 obj1 = new MyAssembly1.Class1();
MessageBox.Show(obj1.HelloWorld());
```

**project b:**

```
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "1";
    }
```

when I perform the following:

1. change "HelloWorld" method in project b to return "2" (instead of "1").
2. build project b
3. build project a and run it

I get message box with "1" as text, and the GAC doesn't always update itself.

What is the simplest way to update project b and see it on project a?

Comment: This seems wrong. You should not be installing to the GAC within the same process.

Comment: Pretty bizarre that GacRemove() takes a file system path.  It ought to take an assembly name, version included.  Well, that's one failure mode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, changing the GAC is unlikely to help an already running process. In this specific case, note that JIT happens per-method **before** the method is executed. Which means MyAssembly1 is resolved and loaded before the remove/install step. However, that doesn't change the fact that this is very unlikely to be a good approach.